# React server stuck with craco and react-scripts versions

Tags: react-scripts, craco

I try to start my app with craco with version 7 and react-scripts 5 and stucks forever in `Starting the development server...`

This are my versions:

```
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "@craco/craco": "^7.0.0",

  "scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_RELEASE_STAGE=development NODE_ENV=development craco start --config craco.config.js",

   ...

    "cracoConfig": "craco.config.js",
```

My craco.config.js file:

```
  module.exports = {
  reactScriptsVersion: 'react-scripts',
  typescript: {
    enableTypeChecking: true,
  },
  eslint: {
    enable: false
  },
  webpack: {
    alias: {},
plugins:[],
    configure: {
      optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false,
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: "all",
          cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
            vendors: false,
          },
        },
      },
      output: {
        filename: "my-file-name.js",
      },
    },
  },
}
```

This does not allow me to start my app but does not show any error or warning message